# How to unfocus from a WebView in UWP

Tags: webview, uwp

I'm working on a UWP app that hosts a WebView which runs in a separate process.

```
var webView = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView(WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateProcess)
```

This results in a behavior that if the WebView has the focus, the containing app can't regain the focus by itself by simply trying to focus on a UI element.

The app supports keyboard shortcuts which may result in different elements getting the focus, but it's not working correctly when the focus is captured by the WebView. The target element seems to be getting the focus but it seems as if the process itself is not activated (as the real focus resides in a different process I suppose...).

I'm currently trying to activate the app programmatically through protocol registration in an attempt to regain focus.

I added a declaration in the app manifest for a custom protocol `mycustomprotocol` coupled with the following activation overload

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (eventArgs.Uri.Scheme == "mycustomprotocol")
    { }
}
```

And the following code to invoke the activation:

```
var result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mycustomprotocol:"));
```

Seems to be working only on some computers, on others (not while debugging the app, only when executed unattached) instead of regaining focus the app's taskbar icon just flashes orange.

I've created a sample project showing the problem and the semi working solution [here](https://github.com/nirbil/WebViewUnfocus)

Any insight on any of this would be great.

Comment: You mean when webview captures the focus, you can’t make the other element on this page get the focus, right?
I have created the webview with WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateProcess, the code works well. At the beginning, I used FocusManager.TryFocusAsync() to focus on the Webview, then I can focus the other element easily via code or mouse operation. So could you please explain this issue in detail and provide your code snippet?

Comment: I added a sample project you can use to see the problem, notice that the taskbar flashing only sometimes happen

Comment: I have tested your sample, the code works well. I haven’t seen the taskbar flashing. Besides, regardless of whether the application is activated or not, the text box gets the focus. So you don’t need to use Launcher.LaunchUriAsync() to activate app.

Comment: try again, press the "Schedule focus timer" button then set the focus inside the webview, to bing's search bar for instance. Then after 3 seconds you'll see the focus move to the target, but the process doesn't have the focus, so if you try to type something in the keyboard you'll still see the webview has the real focus. Do the same with the other button and you'll see it's resolved. As I said the flashing only happens on some computers, its very unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue. I found that when we switch the focus with the mouse, the focus can be transferred to the TextBlock. So you could solve this question through **simulating mouse input**.

Please use the following code to instead `FocusTarget.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic)`.

As follows:

```
                    InputInjector inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();

                    var infoDown = new InjectedInputMouseInfo();

                  // adjust your mouse position to the textbox through changing infoDown.DeltaX,infoDown.DeltaY

                    infoDown.DeltaX = 10;   //change

                    infoDown.DeltaY = -150; //change

                    infoDown.MouseOptions = InjectedInputMouseOptions.LeftDown;

                    var infoUp = new InjectedInputMouseInfo();

                    infoUp.DeltaX = 0;

                    infoUp.DeltaY = 0;

                    infoUp.MouseOptions = InjectedInputMouseOptions.LeftUp;

                    inputInjector.InjectMouseInput(new[] { infoDown, infoUp });
```

Note: If you use the input injection APIs, you need to add inputInjectionBrokered Capabilitiy in your Package.appxmanifest.
But this Capabilitiy is a **restricted Capabilitiy**, you can’t publish this app in store, which can’t pass the verification.

Comment: Thanks for this, but the app needs to pass store verification, so can't use restricted capabilities...

Comment: Derive from the official document, if your app declares any restricted capabilities, you must provide info during the [app submission process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-submissions) in order to be approved to publish the app to the Microsoft Store. You provide this info on the [Submission options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/manage-submission-options#restricted-capabilities) page of your submission, explaining how your app uses each restricted capability that it declares.

Comment: Besides, if you create webview with SameThread, the issue doesn’t happen. Or you could cancel the three-second delay operations and change focus immediately after clicking the button, which also works.

Comment: True re SameThread (and SeparateThread as well) but that's also an impossibility as the app is an actual browser and needs to be able to stably handle multiple views. The delay was just to allow a tester to set focus inside the webview before the actual focus is invoked. In reality there's a JS script injected to the view which captures and forwards keyboard commands

Comment: We are consulting other engineers for your question. There may be some delay.

Answer (score 0):

I've been in discussions with a WebView software engineer. The problem is that the separate process still wants to own focus if you try to move the focus away from the webview.  His solution is to ask the other process' web engine to give up focus with the following call:

_= webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "window.departFocus('up', { originLeft: 0, originTop: 0, originWidth: 0, originHeight: 0 });" });

You can call it before trying to change the focus to your target. I ran various tests and it works consistently.